# Angle between two integer-coordinate vectors $\pi \cdot r$, which $r \neq \frac{1}{2}$ is rational

Tags: geometry, vectors, angle

Are there two vectors $u=(x,y)$, $v=(z,t)$ with integer and both non-zero coordinates (for excluding trivial solutions) such that the $\widehat{uv}$, the angle between $u$ and $v$, is equal to $r \cdot \pi$, where $r \neq \frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$?

If such, is there a rule to form all such vectors given the angle $r\cdot \pi$?

Comment: $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$

Comment: $u = (5,1)$ and $v=(4,6)$ is one pair: because they have 45 degrees ($\pi/4$ radians). Can we get analogous vectors for $\pi/3$? For example

Answer (score 0):

$(0,1), (1,1)$ would fit the bill $(r = \frac 14)$

So would $(3,2), (-2,3)$ and $(3,2), (-3,-2)$

Update

$(3,1),(1,2)$ would have non-zero coordinates and $r = \frac 14$

Comment: No: $(0,1)$ has first coordinate equal to 0. Any $(x, y)$, $(-y, x)$ has 0 angle. So it does not fit.

Comment: We can still find examples where $r = \frac 14$  Regarding $(x,y), (-y,x),$ the angle is $\frac {\pi}{2}.$   A zero angle is would be $(x,y),(2x,2y)$